# How to change kernel security level?

Tags: macos, kernel

My Mac had a `kernel` `security` level of `0`. Then, I changed the kernel security level to `1`.

Here's how I changed it to `1`: `sysctl kern.securelevel=1`

I'd like to change it back to `0` because my `hosts` file has a system immutable flag on it.

This is the code for that- `sudo chflags schg /etc/hosts`

I'd like to take away the system immutable flag, and that starts with changing the security level back to `0`.

I've tried to boot into single-user mode. I shut down my computer and then held down `cmd+S` when I rebooted. It shows a black screen and white code scrolling across the screen and then went into the regular user selection field. Then, I put in my password to log in and it showed more white code scrolling across the screen and then it logged me in and everything appears normal.

This is related to this

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282339/protect-hosts-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are having trouble getting into single user mode. Typically holding command-S after power on should work, but as a work around you can specify single user mode as a boot parameter.

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-s"
```

Once you are done, unset the arg(s):

```
sudo nvram -d boot-args
```

If you are using file vault, you still need to enter your username and password to unlock the volume, so don't take needing a username as an indication that something is neccesarily wrong.

Comment: I tried this and I got the following error `nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) not permitted`

Comment: According to this thread https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256138/trying-to-set-boot-args-with-nvram-gets-general-error-on-sierra, I may be able to run `csrutil enable --without kext` in recovery mode. Can I undo that afterward?

Comment: Hi! Not making this answer correct because it doesn't resolve this error

Comment: Actually use `csrutil enable --without nvram` to allow nvram writing

Answer (score 1):

The setting of the sysctl doesn't affect your /etc/hosts immutability. What does is one of two:

A) Pre MacOS 10.15, "System Integrity Protection" (SIP) adds a "restricted" flag to files in /etc, with /etc/hosts being one of them

B) In early MacOS 10.15 /etc is part of the root filesystem, which is mounted read-only, so /etc/hosts can't be modified. Also, above mentioned SIP prevents you from remounting (mount -o remount,rw /). This has later changed and /etc is redirected to /System/Volumes/Data, but you didn't indicate which version of MacOS you're on.

What to do:

- Try 'df /etc/hosts' to see where /etc is mounted.
- Try 'ls -lO /etc/hosts'. This will show you an extra column of flags. If you *do* have schg, it will be there (but it's never on by default, so likely it won't if you didn't have it on).
- If you see "restricted", then you need to boot into recovery. That's CMD-R, and then go to Utilties menu, open a terminal, and then either edit whatever needs editing, or (and do this only if you're absolutely fine with repercussions):

i) Either disable SIP for filesystem checks (NOT recommended)
ii) selectively enable /etc/hosts in /System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf (which labels all files and causes the setting of the "restricted" flag).

Comment: This does not answre my question because it does not answer how to change the security level

Comment: Oh. I thought that was unneeded given the explanation. To toggle kern.securelevel on you can do sysctl kern.securelevel=1 (as root) but, once set, you can't unset it. So if it's already set on there's some startup file (likely in /etc) which turned it on. grep secure level /etc/* to find it, then edit it (subject to above) to remove the line.